# TFS Rest API 2018: how to query SharedSteps and TestCase through TestManagementHttpClient

Tags: azure-devops, testcase, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using this code to get sharedsteps and testcase through testmanagement using TFS OM API.
But ***how can i query SharedSteps and testcase using TestManagementHttpClient in  TFS REST API 2018*** , kindly suggest me.

```
            string batchQuery = "SELECT * FROM workitem where Id IN (22233,21425,24512) ORDER BY [Id] desc";
            ITestManagementService testManagementService = (ITestManagementService)_teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ITestManagementService));
            ITestManagementTeamProject _testManagementProject = testManagementService.GetTeamProject(Name);

            List<ISharedStep> sharedStepsWIList = _testManagementProject.SharedSteps.Query(batchQuery).ToList();

            List<ITestCase> tfsTestCaseCol = _testManagementProject.TestCases.Query(batchQuery).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in TestManagementHttpClient to get test cases and shared steps.

Test Case and Shared Steps are work item types, so you can use the Query method in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient` to get these information.

Comment: But how could i get its steps field having attachments, actions, expected result and a shared step if it is defined in testcase step

Comment: @Hira_29feb Get the value of "Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Steps" field of the workitem, the steps are stored in XML format.